# Visualise data relationships using Node-Link paradigm in JavaScript?

Tags: d3.js, javascript, nodes, data-visualization

Which open-source JavaScript framework/library assists in visually traversing data in a graph (node-link) way?

---

[image: entity 2 starting point]

Some technical details which illustrate what I am seeking:

- Requires passing in: `(k=max number of nearest-neighbours to show), (starting point)`
- Given `k=3` and clicking of "Entity 1"; the graph should centre on "Entity 1", displaying only: "Entity 1", "Entity 2" and the two linked nodes to the left of it
- JSON data source which will require a new HTTP request if node is not within previous request

Comment: Yes, you can do something like that with D3. Almost any other library should be fine as well. Note that I'm not aware of anything that will provide functionality that you've described out of the box though.